# design the feature in LinkedIn where it computes how many hops there are between you and another person?

Tags: sql, database-design, graph

This was questioned in quora, and I'm really interested in the most efficient answer. 
I think one way is a sql db or a document based db

> get all your connections, then all your connection's connections, and
>   then theirs,  and check if the person you are looking at is somewhere
>   in that list.

Taking into account an average of 500 connections per person, and an indexed by user_id db, this will be 3 queries max to the db.

I am interested in a **graph db solution** which I know very little about to see this feature can be greatly improved.

Answer (score 2):

In a graph database such a task is a typical path finding task. It is solved using algorithms built into the system. For example in Neo4j: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html

When you find the shortest path between persons you can easily calculate number of edges (hops in terms of your question) between them.

Graph databases has a great advantage in such kind of tasks over relational or key-value databases as they can use effective graph algorithms such as Dijkstra's algorithm.